# Angular-material-data-table doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, infinite-scroll, angular-datatables

I'm doing a web app and I'm using angular-data-table to display data in infinite scroll.
Now, for testing, I'm using a very little table (height: 150px), and I want to retrieve 4 items each time the user scroll.
But actually (always for test) I don't send the index of position to the server, so for now it retrieve all data in the database (that contains 11 items).
This is the code:

```
angular.module('app').controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'DataSrv', function ($scope, DataSrv) {
$scope.testData = {
    numLoaded_: 0,
    toLoad_: 0,
    items: [],
    // Required.
    getItemAtIndex: function(index) {
        if (index > this.numLoaded_) {
            this.fetchMoreItems_(index);
            return null;
        }
        return this.items[index];
    },
    // Required.
    // For infinite scroll behavior, we always return a slightly higher
    // number than the previously loaded items.
    getLength: function() {
        return this.numLoaded_ + 2;
    },
    fetchMoreItems_: function(index) {
        if (this.toLoad_ < index) {
            this.toLoad_ += 2;

            var searchObject= {};
            searchObject.SearchCriteria = $scope.searchCriteria;
            searchObject.Local = $scope.filterLocal;

            var that = this;
            DataSrv.getData.get(
                {}, function (data) {
                            that.items = that.items.concat(data);
                            that.numLoaded_ = that.toLoad_;
                }, function (error) {
                    alert(error);
                }
            ); 
        }

    }
};
}]);
```

HTML:

```
  <md-virtual-repeat-container>  
  <md-table-container>
    <table md-table>
      <thead md-head>
        <tr md-row>
          <th md-column>Title</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody md-body>
        <tr md-row md-select-id="name" md-auto-select md-virtual-repeat="item in testData" md-on-demand>
          <td md-cell>{{item.title}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </md-table-container>
  </md-virtual-repeat-container>
```

The problem is that if I write this in the html code

```
<ul>
 <li ng-repeat="item in testData.items">{{item.title}}</li>
</ul>
```

and if I write the page for the first time, it shows more than 20 items (repeated). So it call a lot of time the server. Why?